# How to sum two rows after count and union two tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to count over two tables and by union to take the results. How can i take the SUM of the rows afterwards?

```
select count(PARTNER_ID) from Administrator.PARTNERS
union 
select count(RECORD_ID) from Administrator.DELETED_RECORDS WHERE RECORD_BASE_TYPE = 'PARTNER'
```

Answer (score 3):

use subquery

```
select sum(val)
from
(
select count(PARTNER_ID) as val from Administrator.PARTNERS
union all
select count(RECORD_ID) from Administrator.DELETED_RECORDS WHERE RECORD_BASE_TYPE = 'PARTNER'
)A
```

Comment: Do `UNION ALL`, in case same count value from both tables.